# png with alpha and color background

Tags: png

my product is using 100+ white icons on a transparent background. How can I save the icons with a color background, so I can see the icons in folder view- but maintain the cutout of the icon? Can I use a alpha matte or a mask?
Without a color background, the white icon on a white background looks blank and impossible to view

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe this is possible the way you are describing it. You could make a version with a color background, save it, and make the content of the second file the thumbnail for the original.

What operating system are you using?

Here's a tutorial for OSX: http://apple.co/1Wu27K0
Here's a tutorial for Windows 8: http://bit.ly/247Uy1J

Let me know if you have questions.